# What are some examples of King George III "protecting [the British] from punishment"?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom

In the Declaration of Independence, it says that King George III "protect[ed] [the British]... from punishment for any Murders which they committ[ed] on the Inhabitants of these States.” What are some examples of this? I searched for it but all I found was the Boston Massacre. Besides that (and even that one is debatable), are there any other cases of the king protecting the British from punishment?

Comment: If I might make a suggestion...This is the second question you've asked in two days about specifics of the Americans' grievances against the British. Nothing at all wrong with that! However, since you are clearly interested in what lead up to the DI, I'd suggest reading some of the other writings prior to the DI that go into more detail (which might answer some of these questions, and possibly in turn raise more). My personal favorite is Ben Franklin's [Rules by Which a Great Empire May Be Reduced to a Small One](https://founders.archives.gov/documents/Franklin/01-20-02-0213).

Comment: @T.E.D.- Thanks for the suggestion! Benjamin Franklin's writings are quite helpful (and they also spice up my essay-writing)!

Comment: You may wish to check admiralty courts, particularly Rhode Island. I have a dim memory of a linkage to admiralty courts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick google search on the phrase gave me the following:

> In 1768, a dispute occurred between some soldiers and citizens of Annapolis, in Maryland, and two of the Litter *[sic]* were killed by the former. As they were marines, belonging to an armed vessel lying near, they were arraigned before the court of admiralty for murder, on the complaint of some of the citizens. The whole affair assumed the character of a solemn farce, so far as justice was concerned; and, as might have been expected, the miscreants were acquitted.
>
> In 1771, a band of patriots, called the "Regulators," in North Carolina, became so formidable, and were so efficacious in stirring the people to rebellion, that Governor Tryon of that state, determined to destroy or disperse them. Having learned that they had gathered in considerable force upon the Alamance river, he proceeded thither with quite a large body of regulars and militia. They met near the banks of that stream, and a parley ensued. The "Regulators," asking only for redress of grievances, sought to negotiate, but Tryon peremptorily ordered them to disperse. This they refused to do, and some of his men, thirsting forblood, fired upon them and killed several. These soldiers were afterward arraigned for murder, through the clamorous demands of the people ; but, after a mock trial had been acted, they were acquitted, and thus they were "protected from punishment for any murders which they should commit on the inhabitants of these states." [*ColonialHall*](http://colonialhall.com/histdocs/declaration/declarationanalysis15.php)

Line by line analysis of the DI, which sounds to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @MarkCWallace I added _[sic]_ to one of your quotes, just so someone doesn't think puppies were killed.

Comment: I can't find the six.

Comment: @MarkCWallace We both have to wait until the edit is peer reviewed.